# Vector Calculus Quesiton

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Find the line through $(5, 1, −2)$ that intersects and is perpendicular to the line 
$x = −1 + t$, $y = −3 + t$, $z = −1 + t$. (HINT: If $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is the point of intersection, find its coordinates.)

I have been struggling with this problem for a day now with no real success. I've had almost no experience with vectors so I don't know the correct way to approach the problem.

Comment: Show us some of those struggles. That will help us craft a relevant answer.

Comment: Treat the coordinates of the point of intersection as unknowns and use some linear algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the point $m=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on the line. The tangent vector at that point is $\frac{dx}{dt}=(1,1,1)$. The line from $p=(5,1,-2)$ to $m$ must be perpendicular to this tangent vector. (Their dot product is zero).

Solve that to get $(-1+t-5)+(-3+t-1)+(-1+t+2)=0$ or $t=3$.  From this you get the coordinates of $m$ and from there, you know how to find the equation of a line passing through $m$ and $p$.

Comment: I did get t = 3, not through the same process I don't think, but I'm not sure what to do after that. Could you explain in more detail what I do with t = 3?

Comment: @matematika well, what is the value of x,y and z for t=3?

Comment: Once you have m in that way and p given, you can find the line through m and p. See the second point here. https://www.mathportal.org/analytic-geometry/analytic-geometry-3d/3d-line.php